# After deleting the cart items programmatically for customer and after adding new product, shipping methods not displaying using controller magento2

Tags: cart, magento2.3, delete, cart-items

> Hi @ll in my case after deleting all cart items of a customer and
>   after that we are adding new product to the cart. This time new
>   product shipping Methods("Sorry, no quotes are available for this
>   order at this time") Not displaying.
>
> If you guys have any idea please guide me
>
> Please check Code below

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Service;

    class Neworders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

    protected $_quoteItems;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItems
        ) {

            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->_quoteItems = $quoteItems;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }


        public function execute() {
          $this->deleteQuoteItems();
        }

        public function deleteQuoteItems() {
            $checkoutSession = $this->checkoutSession;
            $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();//returns all the items in session
            foreach ($allItems as $item) {
                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                $quoteItem = $this->_quoteItems->load($itemId);
                $quoteItem->delete();
            } 

            //Second Way

            $cartObject = $this->cart->truncate(); 
            $cartObject->saveQuote();
        }

}
```